# auto layout in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

Good day, i am developing an android app which generates comic like albums, i need to fit this comic to any screen width but i have trouble doing it coz of the layouts, its very odd and doesn't seem to be aligned with one another, here : [image]

those boxe are composed of `FrameLayout`s which contains and `ImageView` (back), the frame which is a `PNG` (middle) and a `TextView` on top of the frame image. So basically the design is very complex and odd, I've heard that there is a way to make this fit automatically on every screen on **IOS**, they called it ***auto layout*** i guess. Is there a counter part of this on android? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). You should be able to achieve what you're trying to do. There's a good blog post [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html).

Comment: It requires ICS as the minimum Target... :(

Comment: @Vyger its actually in the support library. http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout